# Is there a way to denormalize semi structured data from a hadoop InputSource to a csv file via Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

Let's say I have an ordering dataset that looks like the following:

```
 {
    "orderId": "349b494a-cd3b-41b9-96be-3e37372da84b",
    "cart": {
      "319ec5de-8c77-45bd-bf46-f87623c898e8": 1,
    }
  },
  {
    "orderId": "f8e2de64-47ef-4446-bbd0-e55463fbeaa3",
    "cart": {
      "319ec5de-8c77-45bd-bf46-f87623c898e8": 1,
      "86bb7e54-3f21-42b6-adbb-0ef29507d4b4": 2,
      "a5605396-ae19-4a81-b79f-dec69d8fc2af": 1
    }
  },
```

I don't know all the items in the catalog (set of items that could be in the cart) up front

The value in the cart "map" is the purchase quantity.

How do I transform this dataset into a .csv file that looks like this:

```
"orderId","cart.319ec5de-8c77-45bd-bf46-f87623c898e8","cart.86bb7e54-3f21-42b6-adbb-0ef29507d4b4","cart.a5605396-ae19-4a81-b79f-dec69d8fc2af"
"349b494a-cd3b-41b9-96be-3e37372da84b",1,,
"f8e2de64-47ef-4446-bbd0-e55463fbeaa3",1,2,1
```

In reality:

- This is a proprietary file format. I have written the parser and have wrapped it with a Hadoop InputFormat. Before this, I tried transforming the proprietary file format to json and exporting as a csv file in hadoop gave me a "CSV data source does not support struct" exception. Ideally I do not use JSON as an intermediate state for space reasons
- This is not ordering data but I thought this example would make more sense. The only thing that is different is the quantity field is a string, not a number

I've written a java program (not Spark) that takes two passes across the data set. The first pass figures out the "cart" headers and builds a static string to column index mapper. The second pass writes the values to a csv file using the proper column offset. Unfortunately this is all single threaded, and I wanted to leverage Spark's distributed parallel processing. I also wanted to use Spark SQL on the result.

Can someone point me to some documentation how to denormalize semi-structured data in Spark?

Thanks

EDIT: The JSON example was only to show the structure of the data. My data is in a proprietary format and I would prefer not to store an intermediate JSON version as the dataset is multi-terabyte (expensive).

I was thinking I could:

- frame the data using a Hadoop InputFormat into a Text structure <- this works
- denormalize the Text structure <- I can't figure out how to do this
- export .csv file <- this works when I use fixed schema

I'm struggling to figure out how to denormalize the dataset as I don't know all the columns I want to add before I process the data.

Comment: probably, you need to generate a valid json to make use of spark for ex: {"k":"v"}.  here is it like {"k":{"v1":"v2"}}

Comment: Spark should be able to read that json file without a custom input format. The schema of the cart object is just a map